# Why doesn't Visual Studio 2008 show you the value of const variables when you hover over them in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging

My question title explains it all. This is extremely frustrating, especially when working with lots of similar constants. It works for Visual Basic projects but not Visual C#.

In general, why do the IDEs seem to be so different for the different languages (e.g. super-charged Intellisense in VB but not in C#)? To me it doesn't make sense for Microsoft to have two different teams working on the IDEs for the two main .NET languages...

Comment: I don't have the answer, but I can tell you that the super-charged Intellisense(ie: vb background compiler) in VB will eat your CPU alive with a sizable solution open. I hope they never put that in C#. We converted our entire solution/product(25-30 projects) just because of it.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project, rebuilding in release mode, and then debugging it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean constants (`const`)? or readonly variables?

Also - if you can't tell what the value represents from the name, then you haven't named it right; most times you don't need to scrutinize the actual *value* of a `const`, since it doesn't change very often ;-p

If you mean `const` - then by definition the value is right next to it... but even so, *when debugging* hover works fine for me (I could post a screenshot if you like). The hover doesn't work when not debugging - it only shows the value in the hover when debugging.

Comment: You mean I should remember the values of all constants?
For me, HPCutoffFrequency is a good name, still that doesn#t tell me the original developer set it to 15.

I've actually seen it work sometimes, sometimes not - but I am jumping between PC's and devstudio versions a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A work around I use:

```
/// <summary>
/// const string (Checkpoint group found.)
/// </summary>
private const string DefaultMessage = "Checkpoint group found.";
```